# Executing function when chain of promises resolves

Tags: node.js, promise, q

I have written code using Q.reduce mechanism where function insertItemIntoDatabase(item) returns resolved promises.

```
items.reduce(function(soFar,item)
        {
            return soFar.then(function() 
            {
                return insertItemIntoDatabase(item);
            });
        },Q());
```

Is there any possibilty to wait till chain is finished and then execute another function or I should chain those functions in some other way.

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: You should be able to add `.then(mycallback)` to the end. `items.reduce` should be returning a promise that will resolve when the last promise in the chain resolves.

Comment: `Q.reduce mechanism` - you mean `Array reduce`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.reduce()` will return the final value from the `.reduce()` loop, which in your case is a final promise.  To execute something after the `.reduce()` chain and all its async operations are done, you just put a `.then()` handler on that final promise that is returned:

```
items.reduce(function(soFar,item) {
    return soFar.then(function() {
        return insertItemIntoDatabase(item);
    });
},Q()).then(someOtherFunction);
```

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of this pattern is exactly that: to return a promise for the result of the sequence. Written out (without `reduce`), it's exactly equivalent to the expression

```
Q()
.then(function() { return insertItemIntoDatabase(items[0]); })
.then(function() { return insertItemIntoDatabase(items[1]); })
.then(function() { return insertItemIntoDatabase(items[2]); })
…
```

You can simple add another `.then()` on it that will call your callbacks at the end of the chain.